# Inequality $3\Omega^2\leq ab+bc+ca<1$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, lambert-w

Creating this inequality I was thinking to Claude Leibovici who loves Lambert's function .So we have :

> > Let $e^{-1}\leq c\leq b\leq a\leq 1 $ such that $|\ln(abc)|=a+b+c$ then we have :
> >     $$3\Omega^2\leq ab+bc+ca<1$$
> >     Where $\Omega$ denotes the Omega constant .

First I have tried to use the Am-Gm inequality unsuccessfully.We can delete a variable using Lambert's function(playing with the condition).And after I have tried to use derivatives to conclude but there is some steps that I cannot follow.

### Edit :

I link the page on Lambert's function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function .Maybe someone can find an idea to prove it.

If you have some ideas...

...Thanks a lot .

Ps:Can someone explain the down-vote ?

Comment: $ \Omega e^{\Omega}=1$ ... $\Omega \approx 0.567$ ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant